# Need help in finding an HTML, CSS, PHP code formatter for gedit

Tags: php, html, css, gedit, formatter

I need help in finding an HTML, CSS, PHP code formatter plug-in for gedit. I've looked into gmate and other plug-ins but I could only find code formatter for Ruby/Rails files.

Answer (score 3):

The way I've done this in the past (though it's been years) is using the External Tools plugin. Essentially, install tested and true command-line utilities that can format the language you need formatted, in the way you like, and then put those commands into the External Tools plugin. Here are the commands I was using:

To format HTML:

```
tidy -utf8 -i -w 80 -c -q -asxhtml
```

To format PHP:

```
php_beautifier -s4 -l "ArrayNested() IndentStyles(style=bsd) NewLines(before=if:switch:while:for:foreach:function:T_CLASS:return:break,after=T_COMMENT)"
```

I blogged about this years ago: http://www.micahcarrick.com/gedit-html-editor.html

Comment: is there any way to say php-beautifier where to put the curly brace? I would like to have them on the same line like the function etc...

Answer (score 2):

There's a list of all the plugins available for Gedit [here](http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins).
It looks like one of their requested plugins is "Code autoformat":

> Code autoformat
>
> Automatically apply a chosen coding style while typing. A plugin
>   that lets the user select a coding
>   style (or even pull it from the mode
>   line if possible). While typing the
>   style is applied automatically, e.g.,
>   with gtk's style "if (foo) {" would
>   automatically put the "{" in the next
>   line and indent appropriately. Not to
>   be confused with templates (e.g., as
>   in Eclipse), no characters should be
>   inserted automatically. What to
>   autoformat:
>       do, for, if, while
>       argument lists
>       space between function name and left parenthesis
>       add more here ...

So the feature(s) you're looking for might not be avaliable, just yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Erik. When I read the feature request above it hit me and what I actually want is not code formatter but a auto indent tool. After writing my code I want to hit a combination of buttons and just see my code in the opened document auto indented. That's all.